# Renaming output file with the name of the first input file

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

I have a mylist.txt list of files containing videos whose filenames are consistently structured as: 
`2021_03_18_19_30_02.avi`
`2021_03_18_19_41_02.avi` 
...

I'm using ffmpeg to concatenate all files into a single file like so:

```
ffmpeg  -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.avi
```

However, I'd like `output.avi` to be renamed with the earliest filename in the supplied list (in this case, 2021_03_18_19_30_02.avi). I don't need to preserve the original files once they are stitched together.

How would I do that in a win command line or, alternatively, Linux bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know when ffmpeg truncates the output file, before or after starting to process the input files. To avoid destroying the first input file too soon, I'd let ffmpeg write to output.avi, and then *if ffmpeg exits successfully* rename it:

```bsh
ffmpeg  -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.avi \
  && mv output.avi "$(head -1 mylist.txt)"
```

Or even use a randomly generated output name:

```bsh
output=$(mktemp)
ffmpeg  -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy "$output" \
  && mv "$output" "$(head -1 mylist.txt)"
```

---

Automating the deletion of the input files:

```bsh
output=$(mktemp)
if ffmpeg  -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy "$output"; then
  filename=$(head -1 mylist.txt)
  xargs rm < mylist.txt
  mv "$output" "$filename"
else
  rm "$output"
fi
```

Comment: So clever - thanks!